# Cosa significa "avere per posta" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Nel racconto *Ti con zero* d'Italo Calvino ho letto:

> Quello che non cambia è il rapporto tra me freccia leone in quest'attimo d'incertezza che si ripete uguale, incertezza che *ha per posta la morte*, però bisogna riconoscere che se questa morte incombente è la morte d'un io con diverso passato, d'un io che ieri mattina non è stato a cogliere radici insieme a mia cugina, cioè a ben vedere d'un altro io, d'un estraneo, magari d'un estraneo che ieri mattina è stato lui a cogliere radici insieme a mia cugina, quindi d'un nemico, comunque se qui al mio posto le altre volte invece d'esserci io c'era un altro, non è che m'importi più molto di sapere se la volta prima o la volta dopo la freccia ha colpito o no il leone.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "posta" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il significato di "avere per posta" nella frase precedente. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: ***La posta in gioco*** è un'espressione idiomatica molto usata:  Nel gioco d'azzardo, somma o sostanza che si punta nella scommessa: 
|| *La posta in gioco*, quanto si può vincere o perdere in una scommessa; ***fig. ciò che si rischia, che si azzarda. (non solo in termini economici)***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In questo caso la parola "posta" si usa con il significato di "ciò che si rischia con le proprie azioni", come puoi vedere a questo link (significato 6):
[Dizionario Corriere](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/P/posta.shtml)

> **Posta:** Importo di una scommessa o di una puntata in un gioco d'azzardo; in senso figurato, ciò che si arrischia, che si mette in gioco con le proprie azioni

All'interno della frase, quindi, si parla di una "incertezza in cui è in gioco la morte". Estendendo l'interpretazione, l'autore ci parla di una incertezza in cui è in gioco la sua vita.

Answer (score 5):

Qui “posta” è usato nel senso in cui si usa nel contesto dei giochi d'azzardo e delle scommesse: «Somma di denaro che si arrischia in un gioco: *stabilire la p.* ... . In senso fig., ciò che si può vincere o perdere in un’impresa di vario genere (anche un bene morale, o la vita stessa): *fino a ieri giocavi con la p. della tua vit*a (Monelli); *la p. in gioco è molto, troppo alta*» ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/posta1/), 4.a). Quindi Calvino parla qui di un'incertezza in cui è in gioco (= si rischia) la vita.